# Empty message body in receive messages from telegram bot

Tags: bots, telegram

We are using telegram bot webhook method and our website ssl is CloudFlare free ssl, telegram bot works and telegram call our csharp api, but text of messages that telegram send to our api is empty.

Anybody could guide me about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in php project. In the documentation, they write that request will be via HTTPS POST. But I received empty data. Solution: use file_get_contents(php://input) instead trying to get data from $_POST